# how to remove a tuple before another value in list

Tags: python, list

In the following code I want to remove lthe pair before values `2` and print second element of last pair before values `3`.

Input is `list=[(1,97),(2),(1,20),(2),(1,26),(1,20),(2),(3),(1,91),(3)]`.

The first `2`, the two itself and `(1,97)` will be deleted and second two again `2` and `(1,20)` and 3rd two again value `2` and (`1,20)` should be deleted. Now list is `[(1,26),(3),(1,91),(3)]` and the second values of pairs before value `3` should be printed so the final output should be: `[26,91]`.

```
N = 10
list=[(1,97),(2),(1,20),(2),(1,26),(1,20),(2),(3),(1,91),(3)]
for i in range(N):
    if 2 in list:   
      del list[0] #remove the pair before value 2
    if 3 in list:
    # print second element of last pair
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the code below:

```
lis = [(1,97),(2),(1,20),(2),(1,26),(1,20),(2),(3),(1,91),(3)]

out = [lis[i] for i in range(len(lis) - 1) if lis[i] != 2 and lis[i + 1] != 2]
out = [i[1] for i in out if i != 3]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[26, 91]
```

Answer (score 0):

First loop: add element if it isn't equal to 2. and remove the recently added element if element is 2.

Second loop: add all element's 2nd position if it's not 3

```
N = 10
arr=[(1,97),(2),(1,20),(2),(1,26),(1,20),(2),(3),(1,91),(3)]
temp = []
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    if arr[i] != 2:
        temp.append(arr[i])
    else:
        temp.pop()
ans = []

for ele in temp:
    if ele != 3:
        ans.append(ele[1])
```

**Output:**

```
[26, 91]
```

Comment: if you change the list into  [(1,83),(3),(2),(1,76)] it raises with error : list index out of range. the length of arr could be changed.